# Why aren't exceptions used often in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

Before this question sounds very stupid, let me explain. I use a lot of C#, Java, and C++. The major thing I noticed was error handling, specifically in 3rd party libraries. In C# and Java the general way to handle errors is via exceptions as opposed to the conventional C way of handling errors, ints.

This is what I commonly find in C#/Java:

```
try
{
    ExternalLibraryInit();
}
catch (ExternalLibraryException ex)
{
    //error
}
```

This is what I commonly find in C++:

```
if (ExternalLibraryInit()) //Generally returns an int, which no error is 0 and a error is
//anything else
{
    //error
}
```

Why do people tend to ingore exceptions in C++? I don't see why not to use them, isn't that what they are there for?

Comment: What codebase are you looking at? Does the code have a history of being developed in C by chance? I see this often in legacy code that started in C and eventually migrated to C++ (but not completely).

Comment: I don't see "why do people tend to..." as a valid stackoverflow question.

Comment: Maybe it's because C++ programmers feel closer to C, which has no exceptions, so it's a question of style. Personally I tend to stay away from exceptions even in Java because I find them very cumbersome to handle. I'm still not clear on what the advantage of exceptions is over error codes.

Comment: This should probably be on programmers.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: by using exception you basically commit yourself to write exception safe code, which can be tricky sometime and downright hazardous if you write C style code

Comment: Java has a garbage collector, C++ doesn't. You should always watch all the memory you allocate , it becomes pretty difficult when you are using the exceptions (smart pointers aren't the panacea). The code generated for try-catch blocks is hard to optimize for your compiler, and the exception throwing itself isn't a fast process.

The exceptions are is c++ with all these cons because they are invented for some unexpected situations, so they should not be used in your program, if it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

The example you show(*the conditional if*) doesn't qualify as a valid situation an exception.
Exceptions are used to handle exceptional situations. In your case the function merely returns a value and both results are ***expected*** there is nothing exceptional about it. The function might be a C(*C doesn't have exceptions to throw any*) api who's source code you do not have. You simply cannot get rid of the conditional if in such a scenario. How you handle the error/exception after the check is entirely up to you. Most likely one would throw an exception and propagate it over the hierarchy but that is after you handle the api in the way it demands to be handled.

As for why people do not use exceptions, there can be a number of reasons(*or myths*), the three most common reasons that come to my mind are:

- During the early days of C++ some of the platforms did not support exceptions.
- There is a sweeping thought that exception handling is a performance overhead. In reality more often than not profiling has never shown any such bottlenecks.
- Most of the programmers writing C++ code are C programmers migrating to C++ and do not clearly understand exceptions as an concept.

Comment: I believe it also has to do with the fact that lots of C libraries used return values as error codes, like libclamav.

Comment: Per your explanation, exceptions are **expected** then as well if you are wrapping a try-catch block around it, no?

Comment: I don't see how you can tell, just from the function's name, whether this is a valid use case for an exception.  You have no idea what it does.  But I would think, in almost all cases, that failure to initialize a library is in fact a valid use case for an exception.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: The note mentioned by OP in the code says *Generally returns an int, which no error is 0 and a error is*. One does not have any control over what an api returns, it might be even a C api, who knows? You have no control over the behavior of the interfaces you use. In this case clearly this seems to be the case.

Comment: Yes, it sounds exactly like a C api. One in which 0 means success, and anything else is an error code.  This is exactly the sort of thing that exceptions are meant to replace.

Comment: -1 I agree with Benjamin; this would be a perfectly valid use for exceptions. And the question was more about why APIs choose to use return values over exceptions. Of course we can't use exceptions when the API uses a return value; that's obvious and I don't think that was the question here.

Comment: @Timo: How will it be a valid use for exception if the api is a C api who's source code you do not have? what option do you have rather than check the return code of such an api? Once you get the return value from the function, How you handle it in your code is entirely up to you and yes one would probably throw a exception, but you just can't get rid of the conditional check.The answer already outlines the possible reasons of why one may not choose to do so.

Comment: I think you are assuming the question is for the person who wrote the try-catch block. But I'm pretty sure that it is instead for the person who wrote the `ExternalLibraryInit` function. The purpose of the function is clearly not to return an integer, otherwise it would do the same thing in the `C#/Java` example, and he would have checked it there too. The returned integer is an error handling mechanism. The OP wants to know why a returned integer was used for the error handling (by the person who wrote the `ExternalLibraryInit` function) rather than an exception.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: You are correct in your assumption. The Q would be logical if OP were to clarify if the external library is a C++ library and **not a** C library. The way I see it now, I am pretty much sure of the library being a C library, otherwise I don't see a reason(*apart from ones I already mentioned*) why not to throw a exception.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a C++ programmer, and I almost never use exceptions because such non-local control flow makes it more difficult for me to reason about what my programs are doing.  I'm very good at reasoning about control-flow constructs that I see and very bad at reasoning about control-flow construct that I don't see.  Others feel differently and program accordingly.

Comment: Exceptions do not inherently make control flow non-local--it is all a matter of how/where you check for exceptional conditions (they are basically glorified return values with additional information and some implications to performance while also allowing inherent exception "return value" pass-through). That said, I hope that your statement that "I almost never use exceptions" does not indicate that you do not perform exception handling for built-in and third-party functions/libraries that throw exceptions. The "new" operator is one example (unless you explicitly specify nothrow each time).